# Python: can you open, and edit a csv file in an IF statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i am creating a project that will use csv files to store data for map cells. is it possible to open a csv file in an if statement? i am not familiar with csv so i will write in pseudocode:

```
x = randomnumber(1-3)
if x = 1:
    open csv csv1
    write to csv1
    close csv1
if x = 2:
    open csv csv2
    write to csv2
    close csv2
else:
    open csv csv3
    write to csv3
    close csv3
```

again, would this code work in python?

Comment: if its valid python code, yes.

Comment: Note that if you have such repetitive pieces of code, a function might be a good idea, or at least some way to map the number to the name of the CSV file.

Comment: You can do anything you would want to do in an if-statement, it's just a block and the code inside that block only gets executed when a condition is satisfied. What you do inside that block depends on you entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a quick and simple python script for you to get started
But please give attention to the already made comments on your question. And get educated on reading and writing files in python. Thierry made a good point to make use of funtions within the if statements so you will not have a lot of repeatative code.

See here some sources to learn about python and reading/writing files. https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

```
import random
RandomNumber = random.randint(1,3)

print(RandomNumber)

if RandomNumber == 1:
   file_object  = open('Your CSV Name.csv', 'w')
   file_object.write('Hello World')
   file_object.write(',')
   file_object.write(str(RandomNumber))
   file_object.close()
if RandomNumber == 2:
   file_object  = open('Your CSV Name.csv', 'w')
   file_object.write('Hello World')
   file_object.write(',')
   file_object.write(str(RandomNumber))
   file_object.close()

if RandomNumber == 3:
   file_object  = open('Your CSV Name.csv', 'w')
   file_object.write('Hello World')
   file_object.write(',')
   file_object.write(str(RandomNumber))
   file_object.close()
```